# Something cannot be resolved to be a type

Tags: java

My code is a simple vending machine. I used centralised parttern to coding. But I found some errors such as in class veding_machine,

```
Ls[3]=new nosmall_cups();
Ls[4]=new nolarge_cups();
Ls[5]=new exit();
Ls[6]=new start();
```

these errors are the same:" Multiple markers at this line
                    - nosmall_cups cannot be resolved to a type"
And also each time when I using Ls[] in class veding_machine, there is always exits an error "Ls cannot be resolved to a variable" such as in below code:

```
 public void small_cup(){
        st.small_cup();
        if(st.getId()==1){
            //s=2;
            st=Ls[1];
         }
        if(st.getId()==2){
           //s=2;
           st=Ls[2];
        }
    }
```

The whole code of this vending machine are listed below:

```
import java.util.*;
class veding_machine{
    State st;
    private int price;
    private int k;
    private int k1;
    private int t;
    private int s;
       public veding_machine(){

        State[] Ls=new State[7];
        Ls[0]=new idle();
        Ls[1]=new coins_inserted();
        Ls[2]=new sugar();
        Ls[3]=new nosmall_cups();
        Ls[4]=new nolarge_cups();
        Ls[5]=new exit();
        Ls[6]=new start();
         k=0;
         k1=0;
         t=0;
         price=0;

    }
    public void setK(int k){
         this.k=k;
    }
    public int getK(){
        return k;
    }
    public void setT(int t){
         this.t=t;
    }
    public int getT(){
        return t;
    }
    public void setK1(int k1){
        this.k1=k1;
    }
    public int getK1(){
        return k1;
    }
    public void setPrice(int price){
        this.price=price;
    }
    public int getPrice(){
        return price;
    }
    public void setS(int s){
        this.s=s;
    }
    public int getS(){
        return s;
    }

    public void coin(){
        st.coin();
        if(st.getId()==0){
            if(t+25<price){
              // t=t+25;
               st=Ls[0];
             }
            if(t+25>=price && price>0){
                //s=0;
                //t=0;
                st=Ls[1];
            }
        }
        else if(st.getId()==1){
            if(k1>1 && s==2){
                //k1=k1-1;
                st=Ls[0];
            }else{
                st=Ls[1];
            }
        }
        else if(st.getId()==2){
            st=Ls[2];
        }
        else if(st.getId()==3){
            st=Ls[3];
        }
        else if(st.getId()==4){
            st=Ls[4];
        }
    }
    public void small_cup(){
        st.small_cup();
        if(st.getId()==1){
            //s=2;
            st=Ls[1];
         }
        if(st.getId()==2){
           //s=2;
           st=Ls[2];
        }
    }
    public void large_cup(){
        st.large_cup();
        if(st.getId()==1){
            //s=1;
            st=Ls[1];
        }
        if(st.getId()==2){
            //s=2;
            st=Ls[2];
        }
    }
    public void sugar(){
        st.sugar();
        if(st.getId()==1){
            st=Ls[2];
        }
        if(st.getId()==2){
            st=Ls[1];
        }
    }
    public void tea(){
        st.tea();
        if(st.getId()==1){
            if(k>1&&s==1){
                //k=k-1;
                st=Ls[0];
            }
            if(k1>1&&s==2){
                //k1=k1-1;
                st=Ls[0];
            }
            if(k==1&&s==1){
                //k=k-1;
                st=Ls[3];
            }
            if(k1==1&&s==2){
                //k1=k1-1;
                st=Ls[4];
            }
        }
        if(st.getId()==2){
            if(k==1&&s==1){
                //k=k-1;
                st=Ls[3];
            }
            if(k1==1&&s==2){
                //k1=k1-1;
                st=Ls[4];
            }
            if(k1>1&&s==2){
                //k1=k1-1;
                st=Ls[0];
            }
            if(k>1&&s==1){
                //k=k-1;
                st=Ls[0];
            }
        }
    }
    public void insert_large_cups(int n){
        st.insert_large_cups(n);
        if(st.getId()==0){
           if(n>0){
             //k=k+n;
             st=Ls[0];
            }
        }
        if(st.getId()==3){
            if(n>0){
                //k=n;
                st=Ls[0];
            }
        }
    }
    public void insert_small_cups(int n){
        st.insert_small_cups(n);
        if(st.getId()==0){
            if(n>0){
               //k1=k1+n;
               st=Ls[0];
            }
        }
        if(st.getId()==4){
            if(n>0){
                //k1=n;
                st=Ls[0];
            }
        }
    }
    public void set_price(int p){
        st.set_price(p);
        if(st.getId()==0){
            if(p>0){
                //price=p;
                st=Ls[0];
            }
        }

    }
    public void cancle(){
        st.cancle();
        if(st.getId()==1){
            st=Ls[0];
        }
        if(st.getId()==2){
            st=Ls[0];
        }
    }
    public void dispose(){
        st.dispose();
        if(st.getId()==0){
            st=Ls[5];
        }
    }   
}
class State{

    veding_machine vm;

    int id;

    public void coin(){}
    public void small_cup(){}
    public void large_cup(){}
    public void sugar(){}
    public void tea(){}
    public void insert_large_cups(int n){}
    public void insert_small_cups(int n){}
    public void set_price(int p){}
    public void cancle(){}
    public void dispose(){}
    public int getId(){
        return id;
        }

}
// operation of idle class
class idle extends State{
//  idle i;
    veding_machine vm;
    public void coin(){
        if(vm.getT()+25<vm.getPrice()){
            vm.setT(vm.getT()+25);
        }
        if((vm.getT()+25>=vm.getPrice())&&(vm.getPrice()>0)){
            vm.setS(0);
            vm.setT(0);
        }
    }
    public void insert_small_cups(int n){
        if(n>0){
            vm.setK1(vm.getK1()+n);
        }
    }
    public void insert_large_cups(int n){
        if(n>0){
            vm.setK(vm.getK()+n);
        }
    }
    public void set_price(int p){
        if(p>0){
            vm.setPrice(p);
        }
    }
    public void dispose(){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
//operation of coins_inserted class
class coins_inserted extends State{
    veding_machine vm;

    public void coin(){
        vm.setT(0);
        System.out.println("return coins");
    }
    public void cancel(){
         vm.setT(0);
         System.out.println("return coins");
    }
    public void sugar(){

    }
    public void small_cup(){
         vm.setS(2);
    }
    public void large_cup(){
         vm.setS(1);
    }
    public void tea(){
         if(vm.getK()==1&&vm.getS()==1){
             vm.setK(vm.getK()-1);
             System.out.println("dispose large cup of tea;");
         }
         if(vm.getK1()==1&&vm.getS()==2){
             vm.setK1(vm.getK1()-1);
             System.out.println("dispose small cup of tea;");
         }
         if(vm.getK()>1&&vm.getS()==1){
             vm.setK(vm.getK()-1);
             System.out.println("dispose large cup of tea;");
         }
         if(vm.getK1()>1&&vm.getS()==2){
             vm.setK1(vm.getK1()-1);
             System.out.println("dispose small cup of tea;");
         }
    }
    public void cancle(){
            vm.setT(0);
            System.out.println("return coins");
    }
}
//operation of sugar class
class sugar extends State{
    veding_machine vm;

    public void coin(){
         vm.setT(0);
         System.out.println("return coins");
    }
    public void small_cup(){
        vm.setS(2);
    }
    public void large_cup(){
        vm.setS(1);
    }
    public void sugar(){

    }
    public void tea(){
        if(vm.getK()==1&&vm.getS()==1){
             vm.setK(vm.getK()-1);
             System.out.println("dispose large cup of tea;");
         }
        if(vm.getK1()==1&&vm.getS()==2){
             vm.setK1(vm.getK1()-1);
             System.out.println("dispose small cup of tea;");
         }
        if(vm.getK()>1&&vm.getS()==1){
             vm.setK(vm.getK()-1);
             System.out.println("dispose large cup of tea with sugar;");
    }
        if(vm.getK1()>1&&vm.getS()==2){
             vm.setK1(vm.getK1()-1);
             System.out.println("dispose small cup of tea with sugar;");
         }
}
//operation of nolarge_cups class
class nolarge_cups extends State{
    veding_machine vm;
    public void coin(){
        vm.setT(0);
        System.out.println("return coins");
    }
    public void insert_large_cups(int n){
         if(n>0){
            vm.setK(n);
         }
    }
}
//operation of nosmall_cups class
class nosmall_cups extends State{
    veding_machine vm;

    public void coin(){
        vm.setT(0);
        System.out.println("return coins");
    }
    public void insert_small_cups(int n){
         if(n>0){
            vm.setK1(n);
         }
    }
}

//operation of start class
class start extends State{
    public void veding_machine(){
        int k=0;
        int t=0;
        int price=0;
        int k1=0;
    }
}
//operation of exit class
class exit extends State{}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //idle i;
    //coins_inserted ci;
    //sugar sg;
    //nosmall_cups nsc;
    //nolarge_cups nlc;
    //exit et;
    //start st;
    int b;
    char ch1;

    System.out.println("*****CS589 Fall 2010***** \n"+
                        "******PROJECT********\n"+
                         "******DEMO******\n");
   // PutLines(3);
    veding_machine vm;
           ch1='1';
           while(ch1!='q'){
              System.out.println("DRIVE for the vending machine\n");
              System.out.println("     0. coin() \n");
              System.out.println("     1. small_cup() \n");
              System.out.println("     2. large_cup() \n");
              System.out.println("         3. sugar() \n");
              System.out.println("         4. tea() \n");
              System.out.println("         5. insert_large_cups(int n) \n");
              System.out.println("         6. insert_small_cups(int n) \n");
              System.out.println("         7. set_Price(int p) \n");
              System.out.println("         8. cancle() \n");
              System.out.println("         9. dispose() j\n");

              System.out.println("         Testing-related methods\n");
              System.out.println("         a. show_variables() \n");
              System.out.println("         q. Quit Vending Machine class driver \n");

              Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in); 
              ch1=(char)scan.nextInt();

              switch(ch1){

              case 'a':
                        System.out.println("   show_variables() testing-related method ");

              }


           }

    }

}
```

Comment: Ah..stick with Java naming conventions!!!!! It makes your code very unreadable and therefore, a pain to troubleshoot.

Comment: Wait, are you putting all them in their respective files as you should?

Comment: I strongly recommend you to read the naming conventions of Java for classes, variables, methods and packages. Without compiling the code I'm guessing it's trying to resolve Ls as a type, as it starts with an uppercase letter.

Comment: @Jubbat while it is horrible to look at, violating the naming conventions cannot produce compilation errors. They are, after all, just conventions and not rules.

Comment: @Viruzzo: yep. Beisdes, this is not necessarely the asker's fault, maybe he's required to fix this code which he inherited from someone else. In Java valid variables names restrictions do NOT include the rule of "no capital first character"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Ls variable is out of visible scope for other methods, since it is declared only in veding_machine constructor. Make it a field, so that other methods can also see it.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close your sugar class (missing } at the end). Therefore your classes below Sugar are not recognized.

Decent formatting in any decent IDE had revealed this in the blink of an eye.

Answer (score 0):

The class declared as compile-time type for the "nosmall_cups" variable does not exist, is not present in the same package as the class that uses it, or you forgot to import it.